# Full-size div with min-height between fixed size header and footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to setup a webpage, but I'm going crazy because of the height of my elements. 
In particular, the layout I want is:

- On the top there's a header with fixed height (eg. 150px) and 100% width.
- Under the header, I need two columns. The left column has fixed width (eg. 40px), the right one is as large as the window. Both columns have a **minimum height** (eg. 600px, same for both columns), but if there's enough space they must fill all the window until the footer.
- A footer on the bottom of the page. It's placed under the columns (must not overlap!) and has fixed height (eg. 50px).

I've tried several patterns, but haven't found a working one yet. Sometimes I end up superimposing the footer on the columns, sometimes the columns won't fill all the available space. 
I think the main issue is the minimum-height requirement, as the problem is fairly simple without it. I know the CSS property min-height, but still can't find a way.

Here's my code (not properly working, the right columns becomes too large, the footer doesn't even show up).

```css
header{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    text-align: center;
}

footer{
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#toolbar{
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
}

#drawbox{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BLOCKS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blocchi.css">
</head>
    
<body>
<header>
    <h2>HEADER</h3>
</header>

<div id="container">
    <aside id="toolbar">TOOLBAR</aside>
    <div id="drawbox">DRAWBOX</div>
</div>  
<footer>
    <p>FOOTER</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: If possible, I'd like an answer that doesn't involve CSS3 properties and exotic stuff, since I'm trying to learn how the easy things work. 
I'm pretty sure that the solution is a combination of "div", "position", "height" and similar stuff!

Comment: Post your current HTML and CSS that you are trying.

Comment: @Atrix done, even though it doesn't really work obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox. Have the outer container (header, main area, footer) be a flex column with `max-height: 100vh;`. Then have the main area be a normal flex layout with a min-height of 600px or whatever, and set the main content area (next to the sidebar) to grow all of the available space via `flex-grow: 1;`. Then as you add content to the main area, it will grow until `100vh` and push the footer down, then the footer will be at the bottom of the page and you can make the main area (sidebar and main content) scroll via `overflow-y: auto;`

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
header,footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.vert {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
section {
  min-height: 200px;
}
aside {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex vert container">
  <header>header</header>
  <section class="flex">
    <aside class="scroll"><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p><p>aside</p></aside>
    <main class="scroll"><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p><p>main</p></main>
  </section>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is flex the only way to do this? 
I'm pretty sure that is possible to solve it using only "position", "min-height", "div" and standard stuff like that, without the need of CSS3.

Comment: @leoll2 You could probably do it with `display: table;` or absolutely positioned elements. What's the aversion to using flexbox and CSS3? If you have specific technology requirements, be sure to put them in your post so I don't waste yours and my time with a solution that doesn't work. Btw, this isn't "exotic." Flexbox isn't any sort of advanced CSS3 or anything - it's a standard display property. Just like `display: table;`. No reason you shouldn't learn it or use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest flexbox as well, only difference with sticky footer instead of scrolling overflow:

Footer on bottom without content overflow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  text-align: center;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
#toolbar {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80px;
}
#drawbox {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
footer {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
  </header>
  <div id="container">
    <aside id="toolbar">TOOLBAR</aside>
    <div id="drawbox">DRAWBOX</div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>FOOTER</p>
</footer>
```

Footer pushed down on content overflow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  text-align: center;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
#toolbar {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80px;
}
#drawbox {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
footer {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
  </header>
  <div id="container">
    <aside id="toolbar">TOOLBAR</aside>
    <div id="drawbox">DRAWBOX
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>FOOTER</p>
</footer>
```